# Обращение к API VK через Google Apps Script

Tags: вконтакте, google-apps-script

Как вызвать VK API через Google Apps Script?

Необходимо написать функцию обращения к api по заданным ячейкам (в каждой ячейке таблицы свой api url запрос) и обработать выходные данные в формате xml взяв только несколько значений из определенных тэгов(числовое значение) и вставить их в таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

Документация по [VK API](https://vk.com/dev/manuals).

Для вызова со стороны Google Apps Script необходимо пройти Authorization code flow. Очень важно, VK-шный Implicit flow не будет работать со стороны сервера. Для вызова таких методов придется использовать боковую панель или другой Web App.

Пример получения списка групп текущего пользователя

```
/**
 * Эта функция зависит от библиотеки
 *  {@link https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2}.
 *
 * @function
 */
function run() {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    // GET requests require access_token parameter
    var url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/groups.get?access_token=' +
      service.getAccessToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
      authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

Следует обратить внимание, что в GET-запросах `access_token` находится в строке параметров `url`.

Добавил полный пример [VK.gs](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/VK.gs) в основную библиотеку.